# Use DEB for distribution of WAR?

Tags: server, apt, package-management, java

I have created a Java EE program with a WAR-file as a result. To run this file I use the JBoss Wildfly 8 server.

Now I have multiple Ubuntu systems where I want to install the Wildfly server and run my WAR-file through the server.

Installing everything manually on every system is too much work. Therefore, I thought on creating a DEB-file containing the Wildfly server and my WAR-file. In a second step I would create a private apt-repository. Its source would be added to the sources list of every Ubuntu system. Using `apt-get install` and the name of my DEB-file would install all the stuff on the designated system.

Is that a good approach? What would be the best approach? Anybody already having done that or something similar?